# Hasse diagram of a total order not linear

Tags: order-theory

A total order is also called a linear order.
But the Hasse diagram of a total order does not need to be a simple single line.

So the terms 'linear' and 'chain' are misleading.

Is this correct?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hasse_diagram_of_powerset_of_3.svg)
is a total order. But itsnota single line

Comment: How is this a total order? Singletons are incomparable.

Comment: No. It's not a total order.

Comment: Its a total order because x <= y or y <- x  for al x and y. Why are singletons relevant? The Hasse diagram in the link is simplified - it omits x <= x links, and links implied by transitivity –

Comment: @WalterWilliamMilner So what is the relation between $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$? Is $\{x\} \subseteq \{y\}$? Is $\{y\} \subseteq \{x\}$?

Comment: @WalterWilliamMilner The Hasse diagram is indeed simplified since it omits links due to transitivity and reflexivity.  But the relation is not a total (aka linear) order since there are elements which are not comparable. Why do you say $x \le y$ or $y \le x$ for all $x,y$. This is not true if you take two elements in the same level set.

Answer (score 1):

In a total order (also known as linear order), every two elements must be comparable, i.e. for all $a,b$, either $a \le b$ or $b \le a$. The link given in the comments above is to the Hasse diagram of the poset of subsets of a 3 element set, and while this relation is a partial order it is not a total order.  For example, the elements $\{x,y\}$ and $\{x,z\}$ which lie in the same level set of the poset/Hasse diagram are not comparable because neither is a subset of the other.

Comment: OK bad example.
Suppose the set is {A B C }
and 
A  ~ B 
A ~ C
B ~ C

Where ~ is less than or equal to, plus x ~ x for all x.
This is  a total order
But its Hasse diagram is not a straight line - its a triangle.
So in what sense is a total order a linear order?
Is it because if you draw the Hasse diagram with links implied by transitivity omitted you get a single line?

Comment: Usually in the Hasse diagram of a poset one draws the "cover" relations, that is you have an arrow from A to B if A<B and there is no C such that A<C<B. In the example you gave, you would still get a line going from A to B to C. Notice that the cover relations do not always give you the entire order structure of a set (for example the real line is totally ordered but has no cover relations), but you can suppose that they do in most cases where you might want to use the Hasse diagram (for example the face posted of a simplicial complex)